# Login and Cancel at Auth Dialog

Tags: facebook, redirect, authentication, facebook-oauth

So I have a facebook canvas page that holds some info and buttons http://www.facebook.com/theminespress?sk=app_289102104446763.

First Question is...
When the user clicks on the app link they are taken to a log in page:

`http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=287405277948067&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fchocolate_sender%2F&response_type=none&display=page&perms=publish_stream&auth_referral=1`

Even though they are already logged in? How do I just get them straight to the auth dialog for extended permissions?

Secondly if the user selects "Don't Allow" on the extended permissions screen they are still taken into the app? I'm not seeing it go to:

`http://YOUR_URL?error_reason=user_denied&
     error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request`

As described in (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

What am I doing wrong? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the facebook's default action. See my answer to this post for sample code http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7886134/facebook-requests-2-0-how-to-change-accept-button-url-to-be-a-url-outside-of/7987489#7987489 - do follow the link to the facebook's help page.